# How to close send dialog, when finished share?

Tags: facebook, dialog, send

I use this method to share,

```
 /dialog/send?
  app_id=123456789
  &amp;link=mylink
  &amp;redirect_uri=theurl
```

I don't want the share window redirect, I just want it close, when finshed, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JavaScript SDK:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  link: 'your-link',
});
```

The Send Dialog will close automatically. Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

More information about the JS SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript

Comment: what if not use js sdk ?

Comment: then you can just redirect